# R gdalUtils::gdalwarp function skips cells when coarsening cell resolution

Tags: r, gis, raster, gdal, r-sf

I have `fasterized` a `sf` polygon into a 30m cell resolution raster. I am now attempting to aggregate the 30m raster to 150m. The `raster::aggregate` function is slow, so I am attempting to use `gdalUtils::gdalwarp`. The `gdalwarp` output skips cells when I coarsen the resolution. Is there a way to fix that?

```
input <- ".../globalIP/alp/footprint/pl30m.tif"
output <- ".../globalIP/alp/footprint/pl150m.tif"
gdalUtils::gdalwarp(srcfile = input, dstfile = output, tr = c(150,150), t_srs='+proj=utm +zone=11 +datum=NAD83', overwrite=TRUE, r="bilinear")
```

Fig 1. Green cells = 30m `fasterize` raster. Black cells = 150m `gdalwarp` raster

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ended up using `terra::aggregate()`. Still curious about how to resample in gdal so cells do not skip though...